# Alternative ways to define markov chain states?

Tags: time-series, prediction, markov-chain

I have a time series of daily measurement data, if you plot the histogram of the data points of the time series, you see long tail and high positive scewness. Also zero values is an important state.

My goal is to use Markov Chain to model the time series, but the measurement data are integers without upper bound, so in order to model it as markov chain, I need to define the a mapping from the measurement data to state space.

There's no obvious definition of different states of the time series data. My first attempt is to use 25 percentile, 50 percentile and 75 percentile as threshold to define the states(0s are a separate state), say if I'm aiming at 5 states.

Is there other ways to define meaningful states?

Comment: This question is a little unclear... why are you even trying to define states, instead of just using the measurement data itself?  Without a better understanding of that, it's hard to give a good answer to your question.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I just updated the question.

Comment: @user1552372 I don't understand this question really but maybe this is what you want. Have you thought of using the distribution of changes from timepoint to timepoint rather than the distribution of values?